Enhance ordering on 280M rows of a column
I've an application which shows records of a SQL Server table inside a grid after applying pagination. User can filter or apply order onto any column.
Problem arise when that table becomes too big like 280 Millions of records. When user apply order to any of its column, SQL Server starts consuming much time to order records and show top 20 inside grid.
I know if I apply an index onto it, results gets faster but I don't know how many columns user can use for ordering and I can't apply so many indexes.
Is there any way to enhance performance? You are open to give me suggestions regarding other DBMS.
I tried to apply indexes which works but I need some other better solutions besides indexes.

Um, is it really a user need to be able to sort 280,000,000 records? That seems completely un-manageable from a user perspective. I would have thought you could pre-filter that down to a number of rows that is actually possible for a human to comprehend.

Unfortunately, Yes we have apply sorting and filtering on 280Millions of rows for a user to perform auditing.

I think it's just gonna be slow then.

Perhaps you can get better performance using columnstore index. Otherwise I don't know either. Perhaps add some filters that auditors have to apply before scrolling through 280m rows. A year range is a common one for example

How many columns does your table have? Can the user sort by multiple columns or just a single column each time? 280 Million is a lot of records, but if you only have, say, 4-7 columns, you might just use an index on each column and be done with it. Of course adding an index means using more storage, which is something you should consider.

If the purpose is for auditing purposes could you load the data into a data warehouse (fact / dimension tables)

@ZoharPeled, I've 250 columns inside the table. User can sort just a single column at a time.

@ZulfiqarAli can you share anything about the schema, the data distribution, and how you are trying to sort the data please?

I have had this exact problem, in my case using Datatables.js and fetching rows server side, giving the (false!!) illusion of infinite scrolling.
I had to do some incomplete things to make it usable.

Monitor the users' choice of sorting order for a while to work out the common orderings they want.

Capture the queries for those common orderings, then run them, ON THE REAL DATA not a dev server, in SSMS, with Show Actual Execution Plan turned on. Write down any indexes suggested by the plan.

Do that for all the popular orderings then study the indexes to see if they have any leftmost columns in common.

Create an index and see whether the plans improve.

Repeat until things improve enough that the user complaints decrease to a dull roar.

Add some UI elements to let users know of slowness.


If you leave the query-capture logic in place in your app, you can respond with another index if a user needs it badly.
It is a bit of an ad-hoc mess to solve to satisfy users of this kind of data retrieval feature. Good luck.
